# AMSlideMenu UI mess up when receives a call (In-Call Status bar)

Tags: ios, iphone

Library : https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu

Problem : When you are in closed menu state and receives a call(Simply simulate in iOS simulator) after ending call or while in the call if you try to open slide menu, Menu will appear as little bit smaller.

Any better workarounds for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick workaround,

1. Go to `AMSlideMenuMainViewController.m`
2. Replace below methods in the file,

> ```
> - (void)openRightMenu
> {
>     CGRect frame = self.rightMenu.view.frame;
>     frame.origin.x = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - [self rightMenuWidth];
>     frame.origin.y = 0;
>     frame.size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
>     frame.size.width = [self rightMenuWidth];
>     self.rightMenu.view.frame = frame;
>     [self openRightMenuAnimated:YES];
> }
> ```

```
- (void)openLeftMenu
     {
        CGRect frame = self.leftMenu.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 0;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
        self.leftMenu.view.frame = frame;
        [self openLeftMenuAnimated:YES];
     }
```

And this,

```
- (void)configure3DTransformForMenu:(AMSlideMenu)menu panningView:(UIView *)panningView
{
    float cx = 0;
    float cy = 0;
    float cz = 0;
    float opacity = 0;

    /********************************************* DEEPNESS EFFECT *******************************************************/
    if (menu == AMSlideMenuLeft && panningView.frame.origin.x != 0 && [self deepnessForLeftMenu])
    {
        //Workaround for in-call status bar
        CGRect frame = self.leftMenu.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 0;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
        self.leftMenu.view.frame = frame;
        //end workaround for in-call status bar

        cx = kMenuTransformScale.m11 + (panningView.frame.origin.x / [self leftMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuTransformScale.m11);
        cy = kMenuTransformScale.m22 + (panningView.frame.origin.x / [self leftMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuTransformScale.m22);
        cz = kMenuTransformScale.m33 + (panningView.frame.origin.x / [self leftMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuTransformScale.m33);

        opacity = kMenuLayerInitialOpacity + (panningView.frame.origin.x / [self leftMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuLayerInitialOpacity);

        self.leftMenu.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(cx, cy, cz);
        self.leftMenu.view.layer.opacity = opacity;
    }
    else if (menu == AMSlideMenuRight && panningView.frame.origin.x != 0 && [self deepnessForRightMenu])
    {
        //Workaround for in-call status bar
        CGRect frame = self.rightMenu.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - [self rightMenuWidth];
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
        frame.size.width = [self rightMenuWidth];
        self.rightMenu.view.frame = frame;
        //end workaround for in-call status bar

        cx = kMenuTransformScale.m11 + (-panningView.frame.origin.x / [self rightMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuTransformScale.m11);
        cy = kMenuTransformScale.m22 + (-panningView.frame.origin.x / [self rightMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuTransformScale.m22);
        cz = kMenuTransformScale.m33 + (-panningView.frame.origin.x / [self rightMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuTransformScale.m33);

        opacity = kMenuLayerInitialOpacity + (-panningView.frame.origin.x / [self rightMenuWidth]) * (1.0 - kMenuLayerInitialOpacity);

        self.rightMenu.view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(cx, cy, cz);
        self.rightMenu.view.layer.opacity = opacity;
    }
    /********************************************* DEEPNESS EFFECT *******************************************************/

    /********************************************* STATUS BAR FIX *******************************************************/
    if (menu == AMSlideMenuLeft && panningView.frame.origin.x != 0)
    {
        if (self.statusBarView)
        {
            self.statusBarView.layer.opacity = 1 - panningView.frame.origin.x / [self leftMenuWidth];
        }
    }
    else if (menu == AMSlideMenuRight && panningView.frame.origin.x != 0)
    {
        if (self.statusBarView)
        {
            self.statusBarView.layer.opacity = 1 - abs(panningView.frame.origin.x) / [self rightMenuWidth];
        }
    }
    /********************************************* STATUS BAR FIX *******************************************************/

    /********************************************* DARKNESS EFFECT *******************************************************/
    if (menu == AMSlideMenuLeft)
    {
        CGFloat alpha = [self maxDarknessWhileLeftMenu] * (panningView.frame.origin.x / [self leftMenuWidth]);

        self.darknessView.alpha = alpha;
    }
    else if(menu == AMSlideMenuRight)
    {
        CGFloat alpha = [self maxDarknessWhileRightMenu] * (abs(panningView.frame.origin.x) / [self rightMenuWidth]);

        self.darknessView.alpha = alpha;
    }
    /********************************************* DARKNESS EFFECT *******************************************************/
}
```